# Do frame dragging carry energy away like gravitational wave?

Tags: energy, black-holes, gravitational-waves, frame-dragging

Imagine 2 blackholes inspiral closer as they emits tremendous amount of energy as gravitational wave, now I tried to intuitively imagine a spaceship doing a flyby(gravity assist) near a spinning blackhole. Without going into unnecessary details(math) how would the spacecraft momentum be affected by the frame dragging effect of spinning blackhole? Please compare with the direction of spin and against the direction of spin and also replace the spinning blackhole with inspiral binary blackholes.

Comment: The question in your body is different from the question in your title.

Answer (score 0):

> how would the spacecraft momentum be affected by the frame dragging effect of spinning blackhole?

It is possible to extract energy of a rotating black hole by means of the [Penrose mechanism](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Penrose_process):

*"With careful arrangement, the escaping piece of matter can be made to have greater mass-energy than the original piece of matter [...] more energy can be extracted than was originally provided, the difference being provided by the black hole itself.
In summary, the process results in a slight decrease in the angular momentum of the black hole, which corresponds to a transference of energy to the matter. [...] The maximum amount of energy gain possible for a single particle via this process is 20.7% in case of uncharged black hole. [...] theoretical maximum energy that can be extracted from an uncharged black hole is 29% of its original mass."*

See also this [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=t-O-Qdh7VvQ).